# uNet Separate Client/Server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I've been working on a small side project which will require maximum performance on the server side as it should be designed to handle up to 100 players. I also want it as authoritative as possible(With of course client side prediction and all that stuff)

I've decided to separate client/server however, uNet doesn't seem to be designed to handle separated clients and server. Instead it seems to me that it integrates each other and I definitely do not want that.

So my question is, how would I go about doing separate client/servers?

Answer (score 1):

Unity [**UNet**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html) does support sperate client support, basically there are three roles

1. Dedicated server
2. Client
3. Host (Server + Client)

For more information see [Network System Concepts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetConcepts.html)